# How does a bagging classifier(average) works?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, statistics, data-science

how does a bagging classifier works(averaging, not voting)?. I am working on bagging classifier, I want to use a average of the models but when I bag models, the result is a continuous value rather than a categorical value. Can I use averaging here? If yes, How?

Answer (score 1):

You have to give more details on what programming language and library you are using,

If you are doing regression the bagging model can give you the average or a weighted average.

If you are doing classification then it can be voting or weighted voting.

However, if you are doing binary classification then the average of 1s and 0s can be used to give you some pseudo probability or confidence for the prediction.

you can do this for non-binary classification using the one vs all method to get probabilities for all possible classes.